# Dib(s) Error no paytype(s)! missing test parameter? - Open Cart

Tags: opencart, dibs

I am facing the problem to installation of the Dibs payment method in Open Cart. It is displaying the error No paytype(s)! Missing test parameter?.

Please guide me how to solve this problem.

Thanks
Pawan

Answer (score 2):

Strike my previous answer...

According to DIBS, this happens if the DIBS account is still in test mode when you have switched off test mode in the shop, or vice versa.